# Disable certain records while fetching records from a database table in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

Im working with SQLite db in android and am stuck making a particular query:

I have a Table 1 with some email ids and I have another Table 2 with email ids and the usernames corresponding to those ids. From Table 2 I need to send only those emailid/usernames which are not present in Table 1. I want to do this using Cursor in android, something like:

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(
                MY_TABLE,
                new String[] {ID},
                EMAIL_ID +" = ?", 
                new String[]{email_id}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
```

**The prerequisites are:**

I don't want to use delete from Table 2

I don't want to create extra column in Table 2.

Comment: See [SQL JOIN](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/). And btw you cannot use that query method for joining tables, you need to use `rawQuery`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NOT IN` with a subselect to filter out results in your query. For example:

```
SELECT emailid,username FROM table2 WHERE emailid NOT IN (SELECT emailid FROM table1)
```

Use `rawQuery()` for performing such raw SQL queries instead of `query()` which builds the SQL for you.

Example:

```
sqlite> create table table2(emailid,username);
sqlite> create table table1(emailid);
sqlite> insert into table1 select 'a@b.c';
sqlite> insert into table1 select 'a@b.c.d';
sqlite> insert into table2 select 'a@b.c.d','abcd';
sqlite> insert into table2 select 'a@b.c.d.e','abcde';
sqlite> SELECT emailid,username FROM table2 WHERE emailid NOT IN (SELECT emailid FROM table1);
a@b.c.d.e|abcde
```

Since @m0skit0 is insistent in his comments, let's demonstrate his query with the same data:

```
sqlite> SELECT t2.emailid, t2.username FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.emailid <> t2.emailid;
a@b.c.d|abcd
a@b.c.d.e|abcde
a@b.c.d.e|abcde
```

Comment: NOT IN, subselect... Why such complications? It's a fairly simple join.

Comment: Yes, as in all programming, there are more than one way to achieve the result. In this case it was just the first one that popped to my mind. For simple questions like this it's 1) post an answer that's helpful 2) move on - no need to cover all options and think too much.

Comment: And btw *"From Table 2 I need to send only those **emailid/usernames** which are not present in Table 1"*

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, and? Added some example to demonstrate.

Comment: I understand that neither of those 2 values must be in table2

Comment: "I have a Table 1 with some email ids and I have another Table 2 with email ids and the usernames" I read this that table1 has only emailids. But since neither of us have crystal balls to read OP's mind, it doesn't make sense to argue over such details.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [join](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) both tables over `emailid` and `username` field.

```
SELECT t2.emailid, t2.username FROM table1 t1, table1 t1a, table2 t2 WHERE t1.emailid <> t2.emailid AND t1a.username <> t2.username
```

This will get you all rows in `table2` whose `emailid` or `username` does not exist in `table1`.

Also you need to use `rawQuery` method instead if more than one table in your SQL query:

```
private static final String QUERY = "SELECT t2.emailid, t2.username FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.emailid <> t2.emailid AND t1.username <> t2.usernam";
final Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(QUERY, new String[0]);
```